# copy constructor called instead of move constructor, why?

Tags: c++11, move

Consider this class:

```
template<typename T> struct pooled_resource: T{
template<typename... Args> pooled_resource(std::list<T>& pool, Args&&... args):
    T(select_resource(pool, std::forward<Args>(args)...)), pool(pool){
    if(!pool.empty()) pool.pop_front();
}
~pooled_resource(){
    pool.push_front(static_cast<T&&>(*this));
}
private:
std::list<T>& pool;
template<typename... Args> static T select_resource(std::list<T>& pool, Args&&... args){
    if(pool.empty())
        return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    else
        return std::move(pool.front());
}
};
```

It allows to create variables that have pooled resources but are semantically equivalent to the non-pooled version:

```
std::list<std::vector<int>> pool;
using pooled_vector = pooled_resource<std::vector<int>>;
{
    pooled_vector a(pool);          //pool is empty, allocate new resources
    { pooled_vector b(pool, 100); }     //allocate again, but then release to pool as b goes out of scope
    pooled_vector c(pool);              //reuse b's resources
    assert(c.size() == 100);
}
```

My actual problem is that for the simple case above, everything works and the move constructor of the pooled resource is called. However, I'm getting for another class that the move constructor is not called, but rather the copy constructor is. Precisely, the class is [boost::compute::vector](https://github.com/boostorg/compute/blob/master/include/boost/compute/container/vector.hpp), that does declare a move constructor which seems to work in simple cases such as `boost::compute::vector<int> a; boost::compute::vector<int> b(std::move(a));`.

I have no clue why this happens and I don't know how to diagnose it: what am I missing regarding the rules for a move constructor to be actually used?

Comment: That move that you have shown could actually be a copy if the appropriate flag is not enabled.

Comment: @Puppy "appropriate flag"?

Comment: @Puppy you mean, *is enabled*

Comment: The move constructor declared is only defined if the appropriate macro (`BOOST_COMPUTE_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES`) is not set. If this is set there is no move constructor, but your code would compile anyway as the move can become a copy in that case. Therefore it's not a useful litmus test.

Comment: I already checked that `BOOST_COMPUTE_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES` is not defined.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm being compelled to question the wisdom of inheriting from a class whose destructor is not virtual and is a useful type, especially when that type is a Standard class. How exactly are you determining that the copy constructor is being called, anyway?

Comment: Also, it kinda seems to me like if you request a resource, if it already exists in the pool, you will get whatever random value existed in the pool, instead of an object with the value you would get if you used the constructor. So a lot of constructor arguments that would set the value of the resulting objects would be completely ignored, effectively.

Comment: @Puppy that is intended behavior, the resources here are OpenCL memory pools and the constructor arguments are always the same (could actually hard-code them in the `pooled_resource` class itself, but as it is now it fits better in my other code). This is not the case of the example snipped of the question, but it is just for explanatory purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was a silly mistake in the class of the pooled resource. This is a sketch of it:

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator = DefaultAllocator> struct Resource{
    /*...*/
    Resource(Resource<T>&& o){ /*...*/ }
}
```

The problem was that the argument of the move constructor is of type `Resource<T, DefaultAllocator>`. Since I was using some custom allocator, there was actually no template move constructor available with a generic `Allocator`, but just with a generic type `T` and allocator `DefaultAllocator`. The fix just requires leaving out all template specifications of the move constructor:

```
Resource(Resource&& o){ /*...*/ }
```

Hope this can save somebody's else afternoon.